# How to pass large packets of data around an OS without writing to disk?

Tags: python, linux, flask, fifo

I want to have a server running where users can upload images via an API and the server can do things like perform facial recognition or OCR on the specific image. I'm going to expose an API using flask for the user to interact with, but the issue arises in getting the images to the C++ ML programs from the Flask request-handling script.

The ML libraries require a filename to load the image that you are performing prediction on, to make this work I would have to write the images from the user to disk, then pass in the path to the saved file. For obvious reasons we would like to avoid writing these to disk if possible, so my question is :

Is there some Linux utility that can act like a file handle and store large amounts of information in main-memory to be shared among processes in an operating system? I was thinking that maybe a FIFO would work?

Comment: Why not use a ramfs or tmpfs?

Comment: tmpfs seems perfect, thanks.